# Voltage divider to measure Van De Graaff generator

Tags: oscilloscope, electricity, static

Imagine one wanted to measure the discharge from a Van De Graaff generator using an oscilloscope. The voltages are way beyond what a typical scope and probes can handle. I was thinking about how a voltage divider could be used to make this possible, but I am aware that the overall resistance of the voltage divider circuit would slow down the discharge from the Van De Graaf (since it's effectively a capacitor discharging).

What would be an effective way to measure the discharge from something like this?

PS: I am aware that you can calculate it, as you know the capacitance of the metal dome from its radius, but I'm curious how this is measured.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean or are asking for.

Comment: @Andyaka I believe the OP is asking how to measure the voltage/monitor the waveform of the output discharge of the VDG generator using an oscilloscope.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm asking.

Comment: not really that much into HV electronics, but wouldn't these discharges be extremely transient, and the main problem being that introducing parasitic reactive components into the whole system would totally change the things seen on a 'scope?

Comment: What are you discharging the Van Der Graaf generator into?  What do you ultimately need/want to accomplish?  Is this a demonstration, or a more controlled experiment?

Comment: "but I am aware that the overall resistance of the voltage divider circuit would slow down the discharge"  Adding additional (parallel)  resistance will speed up the discharge time.

Comment: They *do* make high voltage resistor dividers

Comment: I'd go with a **very large resistor* chain divider.. Or potentially a small flat plate capacitor placed in the vicinity of the ball, though that might be hard to calibrate. Mind you.. just tapping a screw into the perspex column an inch or so up, might get you a proportional voltage too. Measuring the discharge current might be a bit more interesting though.

Comment: @Nick well I frequently discharge my own VDG by touching it with a fork (since the dome is small the charge stored is small). I guess if I wanted to measure the waveform during that I'd need to build a resistor dividers that adds up to a total load of 2MOhms (roughly the same as me)?

Comment: If you wanted to measure the charged voltage of a van de graaf generator, you'd probably use an electroscope rather than a voltmeter or oscilloscope.

Comment: Very high ohmic R-C parallel ladder or field mill. What bandwidth are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Usually for high voltage they use Capacitance dividers rather than resistive dividers.

[image: schematic]

The 1st stands about 1m tall and rated for 100kV, 2nd is rated for 400kV is 1~2m

and  2000kV not shown would be very tall,  really!

Double donuts reduce e-field gradient which otherwise would lower breakdown voltage.

[image]

When testing HVDC, it becomes more of a challenge for testing as ANY insulator surface oxidation becomes a transport for charge flow and reduced breakdown threshold, starting with repetitive partial discharge or "corona" is visible before BDV is reached.

Testing a 5MVA transformer 40kV, a 200kV bushing (insulator) for me arc'd at 90kVdc.  Since BIL200 only means for 200kV lightning impulse rating it failed below 100kV even after alcohol wipe, so I had to add 2nd bushing in series to test over 150kVdc for a contaminated oil insulation test I tried out.  It ticked like a FET relaxation oscillator and an AM Radio could easily hear it.  Even the epoxy paint got charged up over steel tank and gave little shocks touching it during testing.

[image]

Comment: What are those second F's?

Comment: I like that better.. though again I Might use a long chain of caps so you can stack them to the height of the VDG and minimize the effect of the wires on the E-Field.

Comment: also. this is "fine" for measuring the voltage up there, but no so convinced it would accurately reflect the discharge curve.

Comment: These are used to accurately measure Lightning transient tests in Transformer factories.  Output goes to 50 Ohm coax with 1ns DSO.  The stand includes both caps to some standard ratio.  A long fiberglass pole and gnd wire strand discharges the divider for safe moving after tests.

Comment: I have used these up to 200kV and they are limited by external line inductance only rise time.

Comment: Cool stuff.... when do you "animate" that guy with the bolts though his neck? :)

Comment: I understand the basics of capacitor dividers but I've never been sure of the advantage over resistor dividers. Is it mainly about heat?

Comment: accuracy, size, safety, ... calculate the R value tolerance for 100kV 1W

Comment: I thought the double doughnuts were for tesla coils, how do they measure the static DC field from a van de graff generator with a capacitor? Do they chop it?

Comment: C divider is the AC transformer to step down V.  For DC I used an ac source measured which charged up big box caps with stacked with diodes to make a series of doublers so secondary DC was calibrated from AC input with charge current sensing.